# Safe places to obtain previous versions of PuTTY

Tags: download, putty

Where can I safely obtain previous versions of [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/)? Simon only appears to offer the latest version on his website.

Comment: Usually, older versions of security-related software are not offered for good reasons – they may contain serious security bugs or misfeatures.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Old versions are available via FTP at:

ftp://ftp.chiark.greenend.org.uk/users/sgtatham/

Comment: I had searched his website for a few minutes and gave up, and then found the FTP server immediately after posting the question.

Comment: You need to remember to thank [the rubber duck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Answer (score 6):

I usually use "oldapps.com" when looking for old versions of some apps. Check it [here](http://www.oldapps.com/putty.php):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can simply grab them from the web:

```
http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.61/
```

Just replace the version number. Don't know the version number? Check the [Changelog](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/changes.html).

Answer (score 0):

Updates for software like this are done for a reason. Various bugs in the software are found over time that can compromise the security of the systems you use it with.

Therefore there is no way to safely obtain previous versions because previous versions are not safe to use compared to the latest one.

Comment: While true in the general case, there are times where someone may need to use an old version of software to reproduce a specific problem or behavior. If this is done in a safe testing environment then the security problems are not a concern.